# Pricing Fixed-To-Floater bond in QuantLib

Tags: fixed-income, quantlib, floating-rate

Wandering through QuantLib's [**Financial instruments**](http://quantlib.org/reference/group__instruments.html) documentation, I noticed no class for fixed-to-floater bonds exist.

Then I was wondering what a suitable way to price such an instrument would be without the need to create a new class (in fact, fixed-to-floater should be just the discounted sum of a fixed rate bond and a floating rate one).

My idea is the following:

1. to extract the clean price from an object of class
   [**`FixedRateBond`**](http://quantlib.org/reference/class_quant_lib_1_1_fixed_rate_bond.html) whose [**`Schedule`**](http://quantlib.org/reference/class_quant_lib_1_1_schedule.html) has termination
   date equal to the "swap" date and whose redemption is equal to zero;
2. to extract the clean price from an object of class
   [**`FloatingRateBond`**](http://quantlib.org/reference/class_quant_lib_1_1_floating_rate_bond.html) whose issue date is equal to the "swap"
   date;
3. to sum 1 and 2.

Is the above proceeding correct?

Is there any faster way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it's correct.  However, consider that it would be easy enough, and more clear, to create a new class (at least in C++; the task is more difficult if you also want to export it to Excel).  The new instrument should only inherit from `Bond` and implement a constructor that builds the desired cash flows via a call to `FixedLeg` and another to `IborLeg`; you can look at the constructors of `FixedRateBond` and `FloatingRateBond` to see how it's done. Any other functionality would be inherited from the `Bond` class.

Comment: Luigi, what do you think of this idea? Creating a new class that inherits from `Bond` and takes, as constructor, an array of `Bond`s and an array of dates. `Bond` A for example is a fixed rate one, and is valid from issue date to date X. `Bond` B is a floating rate one and is valid from date X to maturity. The "combined" class will take the cashflows of `Bond` A from issue date to date X and the cashflows of `Bond` B from date X to maturity. This way, the "combined" class will be totally generic, and could be used to combine any kind of bonds...

Comment: ...I could create a step-up bond by combining two `FloatingRateBond`s with different spreads. I could create a bond which changes cap or floor at a certain date by combining two `FloatingRateBond`s with different caps and/or floors. The fixed-to-floater, as we already said, is the combination of a `FixedRateBond` with a `FloatingRateBond`, etc.

Comment: That would work, too. Or you could just write a function that takes the same arguments and returns a  vector of cashflows that can be passed to the existing Bond constructor.

Comment: @LuigiBallabio Don't you think it would be easier to just create one fixed schedule and one floating schedule and then group them into `ql.bond` ? 

`ql.Bond(0, self.calendar, self.settlement_date,[fixed_leg + floating_leg],ql.Following)`

Comment: Yes, that would work, too.